# how to write terraform output for nested objects

Tags: terraform

My terraform plan looks like this, I m trying to create alerting policy and I need help in writing the output file

```
  # google_monitoring_alert_policy.alert_policy["airflow"] will be created
  + resource "google_monitoring_alert_policy" "alert_policy" {
      + combiner              = "OR"
      + creation_record       = (known after apply)
      + display_name          = "Alert For Npe-Air"
      + enabled               = true
      + id                    = (known after apply)
      + name                  = (known after apply)
      + notification_channels = (known after apply)
      + project               = "prj-"
      + user_labels           = {
          + "domain"        = "datapltf"
          + "env"           = "npe"
          + "project-id"    = "prj-"
          + "resource-type" = "alt"
        }

      + alert_strategy {
          + auto_close = "604800s"
        }

      + conditions {
          + display_name = "Cloud Composer Environment - Healthy"
          + name         = (known after apply)

          + condition_threshold {
              + comparison      = "COMPARISON_LT"
              + duration        = "0s"
              + filter          = "resource.type = \"cloud_composer_environment\" AND metric.type = \"composer.googleapis.com/environment/healthy\" project=\"prj-\""
              + threshold_value = 0.5

              + aggregations {
                  + alignment_period   = "600s"
                  + per_series_aligner = "ALIGN_FRACTION_TRUE"
                }

              + trigger {
                  + count = 1
                }
            }
        }
      + conditions {
          + display_name = "Cloud Composer Environment - Database Health"
          + name         = (known after apply)

          + condition_threshold {
              + comparison      = "COMPARISON_LT"
              + duration        = "120s"
              + filter          = "resource.type = \"cloud_composer_environment\" AND metric.type = \"composer.googleapis.com/environment/database_health\" project=\"prj-\""
              + threshold_value = 0.5

              + aggregations {
                  + alignment_period   = "600s"
                  + per_series_aligner = "ALIGN_FRACTION_TRUE"
                }

              + trigger {
                  + count = 1
                }
            }
        }
```

How can I write the output.tf in a way that it can output  as follows,

```
"Cloud Composer Environment - Database Health" = 'conditions.name'
"Cloud Composer Environment - Healthy"         = 'conditions.name'
```

The conditions.name is unique to the alert that is being created which is know only after terraform apply, How can I write the output file for this.
Some of the things i tried in output.tf file is as follows

```
│ Error: Unsupported attribute
│
│   on output.tf line 2, in output "alert_policies_id":
│    2:   value =[for p in google_monitoring_alert_policy.alert_policy : p.conditions.name]
│     ├────────────────
│     │ p.conditions is list of object with 2 elements
│
│ Can't access attributes on a list of objects. Did you mean to access
│ attribute "name" for a specific element of the list, or across all elements
│ of the list?

│ Error: Unsupported attribute
│
│   on output.tf line 2, in output "alert_policies_id":
│    2:   value ={for p in google_monitoring_alert_policy.alert_policy : p.conditions.display_name=>p.conditions.name}
│     ├────────────────
│     │ p.conditions is list of object with 2 elements
│
│ Can't access attributes on a list of objects. Did you mean to access
│ attribute "display_name" for a specific element of the list, or across all
│ elements of the list?
'╷
│ Error: Invalid object key
│
│   on output.tf line 2, in output "alert_policies_id":
│    2:   value ={for p in google_monitoring_alert_policy.alert_policy : p=>p.id}
│
│ The key expression produced an invalid result: string required.
```

Comment: What have you tried and why it does not work? Any errors?

Comment: added the outputs i tried

Comment: And what is the TF code producing the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it what you looking for?

- main.tf

```
locals {

  big_object = {
      combiner              = "OR"
      creation_record       = "(known after apply)"
      display_name          = "Alert For Npe-Air"
      enabled               = true
      id                    = "(known after apply)"
      name                  = "(known after apply)"
      notification_channels = "(known after apply)"
      project               = "prj-"
      user_labels           = {
          "domain"        = "datapltf"
          "env"           = "npe"
          "project-id"    = "prj-"
          "resource-type" = "alt"
      }

      alert_strategy = {
          auto_close = "604800s"
      }

      conditions = [
      {
          display_name = "Cloud Composer Environment - Healthy"
          name         = "CONDITIONS_NAME1"

          condition_threshold = {
              comparison      = "COMPARISON_LT"
              duration        = "0s"
              filter          = "resource.type = \"cloud_composer_environment\" AND metric.type = \"composer.googleapis.com/environment/healthy\" project=\"prj-\""
              threshold_value = 0.5

              aggregations = {
                  alignment_period   = "600s"
                  per_series_aligner = "ALIGN_FRACTION_TRUE"
              }

              trigger = {
                  count = 1
              }
          }
      },
      {
          display_name = "Cloud Composer Environment - Database Health"
          name         = "CONDITIONS_NAME2"

          condition_threshold = {
              comparison      = "COMPARISON_LT"
              duration        = "120s"
              filter          = "resource.type = \"cloud_composer_environment\" AND metric.type = \"composer.googleapis.com/environment/database_health\" project=\"prj-\""
              threshold_value = 0.5

              aggregations = {
                  alignment_period   = "600s"
                  per_series_aligner = "ALIGN_FRACTION_TRUE"
                }

              trigger = {
                  count = 1
              }
          }
      }
      ]
    }
}

terraform {
  required_version = "~> 1.2"

  required_providers {}
}


output big_object_as_list_of_dicts {
  value = [for x in local.big_object.conditions : {"${x.display_name}" = "${x.name}"}]
}

output big_object_as_list_of_strings {
  value = [for x in local.big_object.conditions : "${x.display_name} = ${x.name}"]
}

output big_object_as_string {
  value = join("\n", [for x in local.big_object.conditions : "${x.display_name} = ${x.name}"])
}

output big_object_as_dict {
  value = {for x in local.big_object.conditions : "${x.display_name}" => "${x.name}"}
}
```

output of `terraform apply`:

```
big_object_as_dict = {
  "Cloud Composer Environment - Database Health" = "CONDITIONS_NAME2"
  "Cloud Composer Environment - Healthy" = "CONDITIONS_NAME1"
}
big_object_as_list_of_dicts = [
  {
    "Cloud Composer Environment - Healthy" = "CONDITIONS_NAME1"
  },
  {
    "Cloud Composer Environment - Database Health" = "CONDITIONS_NAME2"
  },
]
big_object_as_list_of_strings = [
  "Cloud Composer Environment - Healthy = CONDITIONS_NAME1",
  "Cloud Composer Environment - Database Health = CONDITIONS_NAME2",
]
big_object_as_string = <<EOT
Cloud Composer Environment - Healthy = CONDITIONS_NAME1
Cloud Composer Environment - Database Health = CONDITIONS_NAME2
EOT
```

where `local.big_object.conditions` should be `google_monitoring_alert_policy.alert_policy["airflow"].conditions` in your case

Also, this syntax should work:

```
{
  for key, value in google_monitoring_alert_policy.alert_policy :
  key => {
    for condition in value.conditions : "${condition.display_name}" => "${condition.name}"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, nice explanation. good learning info.